# Nested Interval Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

How  can  we  prove  that  rational  number  line  does  not  satisfy  Nested  Interval  Theorem?  Of  course  in  general  not  only  one  example.

Comment: One example proves that $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't have the property.

Comment: Hmm. You  want  to  say  one  counterexample  is  sufficient?

Comment: Yes, one counterexample is sufficient to prove that some structure doesn't have a "for all xyz, it follows that uvw" property.

Comment: Ok  counterxample  exists. But  i  am  reading  one  book  and  there  is  a  problem  it  says  that  Prove  that  if         I(n)= [a(n),b(n)]  are nested  intervals  of  rational  numbers  then  intersection  of  I(n)  is  empty

Comment: That is something stronger. And wrong, unless you impose certain restrictions on the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$. $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left[ 2 - \tfrac{1}{n},2+\tfrac{1}{n}\right] = \{2\}.$$

Comment: Sorry  i  forgot  to  say: if  a(n)<x<b(n)  then  x is  in  Q  or  every  elements  between  a(n)  and  b(n)  are  also  rational.

Comment: But  i  think  this  condition  says  that  your  example  does  not  satisfy  because  there  are  infinitely  many  irrational between  2-1/n  and  2+1/n

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample would be one such that the intersection is a single point but the point is not rational. That is if we let

$$I_1 = [3,4]$$
$$I_2 = [3.1,3.2]$$
$$I_3 = [3.14, 3.15]$$
$$I_4 = [3.141, 3.142]$$

and so on. Then the intervals are all intervals of rational numbers but their intersections would be $\{\pi\}$ which is neither a (rational) singleton nor a (rational) interval.

More generally: Let $x$ be any non rational. Then we can find two rational sequences $a_n, b_n$ that converge to $x$ and such that $a_n$ is monotonically increasing and $b_n$ is monotonically decreasing. Letting $I_n = [a_n,b_n]$, we get

$$\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n = \{x\}$$

which is again not a (rational) singleton nor a (rational) interval.

Comment: Ok  i  know  this  example  (in  wikipedia). But  my  question  with  detail  is  this :  {a<=x<=b : a,b,x  is  in Q}. If  we  define  I(n)=[a(n),b(n)]  with  this  property  and  if  I(n)  are  nested  then  show  that  intersection  of  I(n) is  empty

Comment: Let us think of $I(n)$ as an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and then look at $I(n) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. That is the elements in $I(n)$ that are rational. Then $\cap (I(n) \cap \mathbb{Q}) = \cap(I(n)) \cap \mathbb{Q} =  \{\pi\} \cap \mathbb{Q} = \emptyset$